# Number of walks in the Bohr model

Tags: combinatorics

I have a combinatoric about a field in Physics. You don't have to be familiar with it, only to understand the combinatoric problem. In the [Bohr model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) you have the following diagram:

[image]

It shows some paths from from $n\geq 2$ levels to $n=1$ level. You can walk whatever path you want. For example, if you are want to get to $n=1$ from $n=3$ you can do the following paths: $\{3\to1,3\to 2\to 1\}$. This means you have three arrows. The number of arrows is the number of spectral lines. I'm trying to figure out a general formula which gives me the numbers of possible arrows from $n=k$ to $n=1$ but I can't seem to figure it out. Is it possible to explain how?

The combinatoric problem: How many arrows is it possible to draw between $n=k$ to $n=1$ to make a path?

Comment: In general for no. of lines between $n_2,n_1$ the formula is $$\frac{(n_2-n_1)(n_2-n_1+1)}{2}$$

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi is this formula true without repetitions?

Comment: Without repetitions. Note that this is precisely ${n_2-n_1+1 \choose 2}$, which counts $2$-element subsets of the numbers from $n_1$ to $n_2$. So you can see how it fits into my answer when $n_1=1$ and $n_2=n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counting arrows with repetition.** To get from $n$ to $1$ choose a subset of $\{2,\ldots,n-1\}$ as a set of "stops" along the way. If you choose a subset of size $k$, then the number of arrows is $k+1$. So the total number of arrows is

$$
f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{n-2\choose k}(k+1)
$$

A closed form is $f(n)=n2^{n-3}$ (for $n\geq 2$).

**Counting arrows without repetition.** Notice that *every* arrow from $i$ to $j$ for $1\leq j<i\leq n$ appears in some path. So the number of arrows without repetition is just the number of $2$-element subsets of $n$, which is ${n\choose 2}=\frac{1}{2}(n^2-n)$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I meant without repetitions and i'm ashamed that it's so easy. For $n=4$ the answer is $6$ arrows. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my answer to make the two cases clear.